# JS - After Do-While loop, the rest of the function doesnt execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, do-while

```
loadNewPages = async () => {   //TODO this needs to be looping   
    this.setState({ pageCount: 3 })
    let response;
    
    do { response = await getMembers(this.state.pageCount++, this.state.size*3, this.state.divisionFilter, true),console.log(response)}
    while (response.status != 204)
    console.log("finished")
    console.log(this.props.members)
    this.handleRefresh()
        
    
  }
```

This code is lazy loading data from a database.
The do while loop is getting an amount of data and checking if more pages are available before re-executing.
Once the response status indicates no more pages the code below should execute, However it does not.

is this a react-js thing or am i just stupid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you *sure* you send a 204 response from the server? 
I'd consider changing your "while" to `while(response.status === 200)`. What if your server is sending 500s?

Comment: You're using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) which means `response` will only ever equal the return value from `console.log()`, aka `undefined`. If you weren't trying to _one-line_ the whole thing, you wouldn't have this problem

Comment: Good spot @Phil.

Comment: @kibibu I was trying to clean up OP's code by running it through [Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) and the problem was made obvious. There's a lot to be said for properly formatting code

Comment: I edited the code, to spread the loops to multiple lines, unfortunately the rest of the function still doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

The comma before `console.log(response)` should be replaced by a semicolon, since it's making `response` be equal to the last value in the comma chain. Since `console.log` returns `undefined`, `response` is `undefined`, so `undefined.status` is always not equal to `204`. Therefore it will loop forever.

```js
do { response = await getMembers(this.state.pageCount++, this.state.size*3, this.state.divisionFilter, true); console.log(response)}
while (response.status != 204)
```

Comment: the loop does finish executing fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, which was partly my own fault.
i was setting a response status 204, which denoted the end of the pages. to reject against the promise.
which spit out an error and therefore interrupting the execution of the rest of the function.

TeeHee :P